# How can I put RegExp in ruby's case condition?

Tags: ruby

something like this:

```
a = 6
case a
when /\d/ then "it's a number"
end
```

no luck, it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used with a value on the initializer, all case does is try it with === against each expression. The problem isn't with case, try:

```
6 === /\d/
```

All that to say, regexes match against strings only. Try replacing the second line by:

```
case (a.is_a?(String) ? a : a.to_s)
```

**EDIT**: To answer the OP's follow-up in comments, there's a subtlety here.

```
/\d/ === '6' # => true
'6' === /\d/ # => false
```

Perhaps unexpectedly to the beginner, String#=== and Regexp#=== have different effects. So, for:

```
case 'foo'
when String
end
```

This will call `String === 'foo'`, not `'foo' === String`, etc.

Comment: Note: calling #to_s on a string will just return itself. However, this model's syntax illustrates the purpose better.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Your code works! but I'm still not sure about what when does, if it actually do the === comparison, why `'6' ===/\d/ `and `6 === Numeric` return false, but put them it `case '6';when /\d/ ;` and `case  6 when Numeric;` actually works

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't work because regexes match against a string, whereas 6 is not a string. If you do `a = '6'`, it shall work.

Answer (score 1):

Because regexps match strings. A is a Fixnum.

If you would write `a = "6"`, it would work. Testing if a is a number can be done with `a.is_a?(Numeric)`

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood what you said, but if a = "6", a.is_a? Numeric => false.

Comment: +1 for let me know the to_a? method, is that the same as kind_of?

Comment: @yozloy: yes, to_a? and kind_of? are aliases

Answer (score 1):

One minor change to make it work:

```
a = 6
case a.to_s
  when /\d/ then "it's a number"
end
```

The to_s will convert everything to a string. Note that your regex just checks for the existence of a digit anywhere in the string.

It would perhaps be better to do this:

```
case a
  when Numeric then "it's a number"
end
```